# Is the Physics for extremely large and extremely small particles similar in any aspect?

Tags: thought-experiment

Do the equations we use to describe natural phenomenon on a very large scale, work as well for describing natural phenomenon on an extremely small scale as well?

Is there any correlation at all which would suggest that any natural phenomenon correlates when we take extremely large and extremely small quantities into consideration.

Comment: Possibly, but it likely depends on your definition of "large scale" and "small scale."

Comment: hmm, How possibly?

Comment: If you address the second half of my statement, I could tell you how possibly.

Comment: Truthfully, I did not have a set scale in mind, but lets say - Does a correlation appear as we go larger/ smaller in size - at the very extremes i mean.

Comment: Again, I would say that it *entirely* depends on the sizes of the scales.

Comment: Could you please tell me at what scale the correlation is present and how ?

Comment: An obvious example would be [turbulence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbulence), which is seen on human scales and galactic scales.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the Physics for extremely large and extremely small particles similar in any aspect?

It is similar that it uses similar differential equations at all scales, which obey the same conservation laws at all scales ( exception conservation of energy and general relativity at large scales).

> Do the equations we use to describe natural phenomenon on a very large scale, work as well for describing natural phenomenon on an extremely small scale as well?

No; there are usually different ( but similar) differential equations for each scale, the underlying frame being quantum mechanics for particle dimensions;, all other frameworks emerge smoothly from that sequentially . Gravity on the relevant scale, human scale, also has different equations that blend smoothly with the ones of General Relativity for humongous masses.

The exceptions are [chaos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory) and complexity . [Fractals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal) can appear in any dimensions depending on the boundary conditions , as well as [turbulance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbulence) as mentioned in the comments when the framework  allows fluidity.

Answer (score 0):

No, on the very small scale, quantum mechanics applies It differs a lot from the observation we make in the macro-world, but the differences in quantum mechanical measurements are (usually) so small when applied to macroscopic objects that they can be ignored.

Comment: I thought QM was the science of the very small?

Comment: @novice Oops.. that's what I mean to put. I just edited. It is fixed now.

Answer (score -3):

It is believed that momentum, energy and angular momentum are conserved on all scales.

Comment: Energy is not believed to be conserved at the largest of scales. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109532, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2597, and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27812 for more.